# One part of the render layer glowing?

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]

Take a look at this pic. I want only the eyes to glow without the armor glowing too (The armor got a glossy shader).
How can I do that?

Comment: For something very similar see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35448/1853

Comment: One simplistic approach could be to use a color or difference key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a pass index on the material for the eyes.

[image]

Enable material index on the layer passes.
[image]

Add a ID mask on the compositor and use the number of your material pass index to create a mask for the glow.

[image]

[image]
**EDIT**

To make the glow yellow you can add color to the mask and change the final mix node's mode to add:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Almost the answer. It's only the eyes glowing. But they glow white! It'd be nice if you guided me how to make them glow yellow!

Comment: @thododo see edited answer

Comment: Straight-forward and cool! Learned a little more! Thank you! @cegaton

Comment: Before this, I tried RGB curve but didnt come out well LOL