# Render layers added back in order after applying glow in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers

I've just had my first attempt at applying glow in the compositor using different render layers.

When I try and apply the layers back together however there is a drastic effect happening that I have no idea how to correct.

[image: wrong]

As you can see, the eyes are now popping out from behind the eye sockets.

I have been following Andrew Price's [Introduction to Blender's Compositor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWcCkQ3943Y) tutorial but cannot seem to get the eyes to sit inside the sockets where they are supposed to be.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, It seems looking back at this that the whole way I went about adding the glow to the eyes only was ineffective.

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing) Highlights a much better solution to give the material a separate index pass and using ID Mask then apply the glow directly to the eyes.