# How can I do glowing halo particles/special effects in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, effects

Now, I've been wanting to create special effects in Blender (Cycles), but I don't know how to do it.

For example (just a picture I googled):

[image: Some effects]
Or:

[image: More effects]

I can't figure out how to do this in Blender (specifically Cycles). Blender Internal had the 'halo' material, which would be one step ahead concerning special effects I suppose, but you don't get half the capability Cycles has.

I've been fiddling around with a lamp/light emitting object, and a sphere/other mesh with a volume scatter volume input, but that doesn't have very advanced results, and is incredibly grainy when rendered, unless you head upwards of 500 samples.

For example, this was a simple point lamp with a strength of 100 and a very large UV sphere with a volume scatter volume input. It took 15 seconds to render (at 150 samples) and still doesn't give me satisfactory results.

[image: My render]

Is there any way to do special effects like this in Blender (especially Cycles)?

Thanks, Flaeon.

Comment: I think you can do this in the node compositor using render layers, emission, and the blur filter.

Comment: @Dontwalk I'm not talking about the compositor, I need materials, because if I use the compositor it composites the entire frame and if a normal poly mesh happens to be in the same frame with the effect, it'll be applied to the normal mesh as well.

Comment: If you use the compositor you have control over what it composites. I don't think effects from both images are done with materials only. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46382/how-can-i-make-a-part-of-a-texture-glow, also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing

Comment: All of the above images are doable in cycles.

Comment: [Halo particles are available in Cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45487/5705), actually with more flexibility than BI.

Comment: maybe related too: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/creating-light-streaks-on-cycles/34383#34383

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found out how to achieve something similar from these comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was working on this clock anyway... Now it glows.[image]

I moved the clocks “Bells” to layer 4 (It could be any other layer than the layer the clock mesh is on. In my case layer 1). I gave the bells mesh a material with “Emission”.

Then in the “Render Layers” panel I added a render layer and selected layer 4 and named it “Glow”. Although you don’t need to rename it.

[image]

Here's the node set up in the Compositor.

[image]

Comment: How can we create the above blue color mesh so that we can give a glowing material.