# ManuelLab: Glowing eyes: How?

Tags: texturing, materials

This sounds like what would be a way to make eyes glow in the dark, but would this affect the ability to change it's color? Would it overwrite the texture? What about making the skin all pure dark like with Japanime models given by ManuelLab?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46382/how-can-i-make-a-part-of-a-texture-glow

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing

Answer (score 1):

[image: Glowing eyes]

This is possible through Nodes, not just menuing:
[image: Locations]

[image: Glowing eyes info]

By using the ColorRamp, you can edit the color without overwriting the texture.

By using the Skin Value matching nodes, you can make skin as bright or dark as the UI would not realistically allow.