# How do I make an object glow?

Tags: light

How do I make an object glow?

[image]

I've tried everything to make it glow but it isn't. I even made a separate material and added the texture again and used a mix shader to mix the texture and glow.

Comment: nowhere in the Node configuration is an Emmision Shader, without that I am not sure how you can create a glow.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89653/how-to-make-small-objects-emit-a-ton-of-light/89677#89677 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46382/how-can-i-make-a-part-of-a-texture-glow/46389#46389

Answer (score 0):

[image]

apperently most of the original nodes from McPrep were useless, so i kept the original texture node and used 2 emmision ones, a mix shader and a light path to make it look like a normal glowstone block