# make specific part of object glow

Tags: texturing, shaders

I am aware of how to make an object glow, however, I am unable to figure out how I make the red part of this sword glow red.

[image: !sword]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46382 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3636 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669

Comment: Are you using Eevee? In Eevee, enable the Bloom option in the Render panel, and give your object an Emission shader and increase the node Strenght value