# How can I make part of my object glow?

Tags: light

How can I achieve this type of illumination?
[image]

This is my result, and it isn't similar as image above
[image]
Can anyway tell me the scene setup, and material node setup?
Thanks

Comment: @Jagredon please use  more specific titles for your questions in the future.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing

Comment: Ok, I'll try. I don't use very much info because im spanish, and i could make non-sense questions

Comment: it seems to be flat... why dont you use a simple texture (radial gradient) on a plane with emission/transparent for the red part and a emissive circle for the centers.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/0c382f0f1385a6ba69b0ae47e32d6ba2

Comment: I'll try! Thx
Anyway, i will edit it with photoshop

Answer (score 5):

This type of effect is not possible using cycles directly,instead we can approximate it using post production technique.

Using a node tree like this:

[image: Post]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the first image has lighting other than the UV Spheres. I would recommend several area lamps. It looks like it might have some volume scatter around the eyes.

Comment: Well, and if aren't Uv spheres? How could i do it?

Comment: What? Could you rephrase that please?

Comment: How can i create that illumination? All the ways, not only with UV sphere

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Put several area lamps around your object.

Comment: And the light node setup?

Comment: And what type of lamps? (your recomendation)

Comment: I just said. Area lamps, with a size of anywhere from 2.5 to 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40065/discussion-between-jagredom-and-masterholbytla).