# "Physical" glows? (Blender Render)

Tags: materials

As noted, I'm using Blender Render for this little experiment.

What I've been trying to find is how to get a straight glow on an object. Volume materials seems closest to what I've been able to replicate but unfortunately, emission light does not work inside volume materials.

If there is a better way to do it in Blender Render, how can I make it glow more appropriately along the area surrounding it? And how can I make it so the edges serve as an actual light without resorting to using many smaller lights?

[image: Doom 2016 Ending with Samuel Hayden and the Crucible Sword]

Another good example is like this alien blaster, the light surrounding the blue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAhRiv-FKbI

Comment: you can use compositing nodes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing

Comment: That would have worked... if only alpha actually rendered the glow over the empty spaces. https://puu.sh/B24YI/f555828403.png

Comment: @MajorCooke For that you could put a plain black behind the masked parts, then apply glare to that and finally mix it via 'Add' or 'Screen' to the original image.

Comment: Can you show me? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Furthermore, I should clarify, I'm going to need that rendered as see-thru and completely transparent with no background associated behind it when all is said and done. There must be no black background in short.

Comment: @Ectras Sorry, forgot to ensure you received a notification, but how would I do that in particular? I've tried inserting it into many different places but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @MajorCooke Yeah, glow on transparency is a bit inconvenient. My previous comment would only work if you'd work with a solid background. But maybe have a look at [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44137/55213) to get glow on transparency.

Comment: Huh... @Ectras that just might have solved my problem, only I used the top solution instead.