# Applying glare to selected color only

Tags: compositing-nodes, effects

I have a scene setup in Cycles that contains multiple light emitting objects on a single layer.

Is it possible to apply glare only to blue colors without having to move these to a separate layer or assigning them a special material id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "correct" way to do it would be to have the material to emit more than 1 in value and set the threshold so that the rest gets cut off. But I don't know your setup so here is another way to do it:

Change the color of the image to filter out other colors than blue. Feed that image into the glare node and set Mix to 1. This will create an image with only the glare. Add-mix the original image with the glare.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was just what I was looking for! It just didn't occur to me to use the multiply node. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

I know it may not be exactly what the OP is asking for, but I arrived on this page when I did my search. If you want to select the bloom on a per-material basis instead of per-color (which is, in my opinion, more precise and easier to apply), you can check this answer " [One part of the render layer glowing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing/35860) " which assigns a `pass index` to your material, apply the glare only on this material, and then combine the two using a simple `Add` layer.