# Separate reflection based on object index cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

It is possible to separate the reflected background , for example having 2 glossy objects A and B and a hdri image as background  to reflect. I want to have a blurred version of the hdri reflected on object A and a crisper version(or diferent hue) reflected on object B.
I am aware that using the light path node and substracting   glossy and singular ray   it is possible to split the reflection one object having the sharp Bsdf , but i need two glossy objects with roughness non zero each .
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Starting with two objects with the same glossy material.

Give the objects different Pass Index.

[image]

Enable Object Index in the render layer

[image]

In the compsitor use an Id Mask node and select the pass index of your object and use that to mix the blurred image with the non blurred one:

[image]