# Double Compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes

In compositing I made a glowing eye effect but I want to use compositing to make another effect. If I do that it would mess up the first one. Is there any way for me to make two different effects so the glowing eyes wont have the same effect as the second effect but would still keep its old effect?

Ok hw about me explainng it like this. I have node a and node b with two objects which are using nodes.

I Want one object to be affected by node b and ignore node a. The other object will be affected by node a and ignore node b. How do i do that?

Comment: Of course there is, it wouldn't be much of a compositor if it could only do one effect per image now, would it?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your current nodes settings and what kind of layers you are dealing with.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: One of your images is not there, would you [edit] the question and add it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Probably what you want to do is quite easy, but it would help if you show your current nodes and a some images of the different elements you want to combine.

Comment: Maybe what you need are objcet ID masks See:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39969/any-idea-how-to-get-the-location-and-bounds-of-object-in-the-image/39983#39983 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35414/compositor-id-mask-not-working/35448#35448 or maybe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing/35860#35860 or this other one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42832/separate-reflection-based-on-object-index-cycles/42843#42843