# Can I make an object invisible in Cycles without letting the camera see what is behind it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, transparency

I would like my mountain to be invisible after rendering. And I want just Objects in front of it (like trees) to be seen, but not behind the mountain.

Comment: You can also adjust your camera's clipping distance, but it will no doubt clip your sky as well. Render Layers may be another option as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make an object invisible when I render in Cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48122/how-can-i-make-an-object-invisible-when-i-render-in-cycles)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the object transparent as alpha channel:

- use a [holdout shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/holdout.html) so it renders as transparent

  [image]
- Place the object on a different layer and use that layer as mask:

  [image]
- Use a Pass index for the object and use that on the compositor to substract the object from the final render:

  [image]
  (click on the image to enlarge)
- Similarly, you can assign a pass index to the material and use that as alpha on the compositor:

  [image]
  (click on the image to enlarge)

Comment: What i tried to do was making things behind the mountain invisivle, while it was invisible itself. Holdout worked together with transparency.

Comment: I would like to upvote this more than once.