# How can I make an object invisible when I render in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, compositing-nodes, transparency

Using the Cycles Render Engine
How can I make an object invisible when I render?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Making an Invisible Material in the Cycles render engine](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36503/2217)

Comment: @David I did look at that question and thought of adding into it, but the question is about animating the disappearance of an object it made no sense...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are some of the options to make an object not render in Cycles.

## To make the object invisible/unrenderable

- Disable the object for rendering (turn off the camera icon)

  [image]
- Move the object you don't want to a layer that is not renderable

  [image]
- Give it a transparent shader:

  [image]

## To make the object invisible to camera but keep the shadows and interaction with other objects (reflections, etc)

- Restrict the visibility for camera:

  [image]
- Using Nodes: use a light path so the object is invisible to the camera only:

  [image]

## To make the object transparent as alpha channel:

- use a [holdout shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/holdout.html) so it renders as transparent

  [image]
- Place the object on a different layer and use that layer as mask:

  [image]
- Use a Pass index for the object and use that on the compositor to subtract the object from the final render:

  [image]
  (click on the image to enlarge)
- Similarly, you can assign a pass index to the material and use that as alpha on the compositor:

  [image]
  (click on the image to enlarge)

For the last three options the Transparent Background option has to be enabled:

[image]

Comment: +1, I like.  However, I don't understand why you said that *Transparent* has to be selected.  It worked for me without that enabled.