# Culling Objects Using a Culling Object

Tags: objects, camera

Today my question might be a bit complex, but I hope that Blender has an easy solution for this. So, let's say I have a scene with several objects in it and I have a background. The background is image/video which has some objects on it. Some of them are supposed to be closer to camera than my 3D models. I have a representative 3D model made for those objects, but texturing it would be real complex. Instead what I inted to do is to use it as a culler - wherever the object is, render the background(cull the other objects). Is this possible to do? Also, a solution for both - Blender Internal and Blender Cycles is needed.
Thanks! ;)

Comment: I guess it is something like object mask. Basically what I am trying to do is to use one object to cull others. Or, in other words, wherever that object is directly visible to camera, it must render the background instead of any objects).

Comment: Can you use the [edit] link and clarify your question?

Comment: In cycles you can use a holdout material. But there are a few options. Read: related?;http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48122/how-can-i-make-an-object-invisible-when-i-render-in-cycles/48123#48123

Comment: UV Project modifier... maybe. But could you post some images to have a better understanding?

Comment: You might also want to have a look at this.  Instead of  fashioning a 3D model you just shape a 2D plane in the shape of the object that's in the bkd film.  Set it's transparency to .008.  That works in Blender's 3D window and using OpenGL rendering.  I'm not into Cycles but I imagine if a model can be used for a mask, a 2D plane could be also. (No transparency though)   The Question - drop to the bottom answer.  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/realistic-rendering-of-mesh-together-with-image/69863#69863

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using Renderlayers

Position your *masking* objects on a separate layer. (In my case layer 2.)

[image]

Go to the **Properties > Renderlayers** Tab. Set the **Mask Layer** to the layer, which contains the mask objects. Note that you have to have the layers switched on in the scene for them to be included in the render.

[image]

Rendering this setup results in the following. The mask object renders as transparent.

[image]

If you do not wish the object to have a *shadow*, set it to a transparent material or turn off cast shadows.

### Using the Material Setup

#### Cycles

Set the material to holdout.

[image]

#### Internal

Check **Transparent**, use **Mask** mode and set **Alpha** to 0.0. Disable **Cast Shadows**.

[image]