# Hiding a plane track behind an object

Tags: video-sequence-editor, tracking

I'd like to create an effect where I reveal an image when opening the cupboard's door. So far I've created a plane track with the image in it but can't figure out how to hide the image behind the opening door. Any suggestions please?
[image]

Comment: Hello, your link doesn't work

Comment: Please, don't use external link only to describe your question..

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183081/how-to-have-person-in-video-mask-added-geometry-as-they-walk-in-front

Comment: Sorry about that, uploaded gif instead.

Comment: Look at creating masks for compositing. You could also use a [holdout object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73932/308499).