# Questions About Smoke?

Tags: smoke-simulation

So I am brand spanking new at blender and just learning the ropes. I believe everything about my smoke is set up fine, but EVERYTHING in the scene is getting rendered (like the smoke domain before I messed with the nodes from seeing a similar problem). Could anyone give me a hand as I know basically nothing about rendering in blender?

[Here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50887) is the .blend for anyone looking :)

Comment: Hi. Please make your title specific to the question you are asking, not just the general topic.

Comment: While you are at it, also add actual info to your question like screenshots, settings, and other details that may hep diagnose the issues

Answer (score 1):

For the smoke domain material, I believe that a Principled Volume would work, feed it into the volume input of the output node.  Change the density to 0.  Delete the default diffuse shader.

Or you can make the smoke domain invisible like this: [How can I make an object invisible when I render in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48122/how-can-i-make-an-object-invisible-when-i-render-in-cycles)