# rendering objects in a scene separately

Tags: render-layers

I know that it is possible to render diffrent parts of a scene in different layers but if the object that i am rendering on a specific layer is occluded by an object from another layer will the silhouette of the object still be visible since that part of my object is not visible in the render from the cameras perspective? If yes, is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You can use a pass index for the object and use the information as a mask in the compositor read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48123/1853

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Exclude Layer to remove a corresponding silhouette

Comment: A single sentence rarely makes a good answer. Even if the immediate problem would be solved by just a single sentence, try to explain what exactly you mean and and how to avoid the problem in the future.