# How to reflect\catch light but be invisible on render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I want a mash was able to catch light but was invisible on render. I want this effect to happen, but the plane was invisible. Is it possible? Or can I cast colored shadow? I need this in cycles. This question is not about "how to make an obect invisible" it's about how to make in catch light.
[image]

Fore example

[image]

I need this happen

[image]

How can I get light accents without white face??? Do you see that light distributes unequally on shaped objects, how can I get only light fingerprint on transparent background?

[image]

Comment: Check out the Light Path node.. maybe this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTFxyNzI5EE) will help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a cycles light emisson object invisible to the camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/how-to-make-a-cycles-light-emisson-object-invisible-to-the-camera)

Comment: @brockmann no, compared to that post I need the cube to be invisible but refract\reflect the light.

Comment: Restrict the visibility to camera in Ray visibility, or use a light path node and Is Camera ray to control the mix between transparent and emission shader/ Read the following link: [How can I make an object invisible when I render in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48122/how-can-i-make-an-object-invisible-when-i-render-in-cycles/48123#48123)

Comment: @cegaton there is no aswer for my question, remove the duplicate please. I need invisible for camera object was visible for light. https://imgur.com/xfMyDN4 at this picture it's invisible for the light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: final]

I couldn't manage to make this "light catcher" using nodes but as a workaround or just alternate method you can use [Baking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html). For this answer I'm using Blender 2.80 Beta and Cycles but the workflow is the same as in 2.79b.

### Scene setup for baking

[image: scene_setup]

1. **Background** needs to be black.
2. **Light** should be fully white - you can change color of it after bake.
3. **Object** may be simple **Diffuse** - needs to be **UV Unwrapped**.

### Baking

[image: bake]

**Bake Type** - **Diffuse** with **Influence Direct**.

You should get a map like this:

[image: bake_map]

### Using it

[image: baked]

Now you can use baked map as a mask to combine **Transparent** shader with another of your likeness. **Color Ramp** is for fine tuning mask strength.

Comment: @sgslav Thanks a lot, mate! I think this is it!