# How can I keep transparency through refraction?

Tags: rendering, shaders

[image: Image showing that the background color gets shown in the refraction object]

In the image you can see that the green background is being shown in the refraction object. Although I have select background as transparent in the render settings.

Is there anyway I can keep the refraction, and make it so that the green part also renders as transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Enable Transparent Glass option under Film panel, Transparent sub-panel in the Render tab of the Properties Editor:

[image]

This is assuming you mean an object with Glass BSDF shader by "the refraction object".

Comment: I am using Eevee, which does not have this option. This option fixes my issue, however I will have to re-design my scene to work with cycles. Which I would prefer not to do.

Comment: It is reasonable to expect EEVEE not to have all functionality Cycles does. It's a "real-time" render engine after all.  You could look into rendering twice(two different view layers maybe?) and subtracting one from another like [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134766/isolate-light-cast-on-a-surface-through-glass/135000#135000) But I am not sure how or if this might work.