# How to prevent things from out of sight rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I was wondering if there was a way to only calculate the things that are currently visible in the frame. My scene has a lot of trees that are slowing down my render times, and these are mostly out of sight. This would be especially efficient especially in my scene.

TL;DR Is there a way to stop things in the background that are out of sight from being processed/ slowing down rendering?

Comment: You could try to move them to a different collection and render them seperatly if needed and then combine the layers the compositor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and these are mostly out of sight

**but we can still see them!**

Please read [How is Cycles different from Blender Internal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal/5821#5821) first.

> Most materials [and objects] scatter light, so Cycles needs to account for light bouncing in different directions. How this is done depends on which [*Integrator*][6] is used.

Objects scatter light even if they are outside of the visible frame.

[image: objects]

If you remove them, you will likely receive a different result, even if they weren't directly visible. There are many [ways to restrict rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48123/30849) manually.

You could do a check with python to see if an [object is in the cameras frustum](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/79172/126675). Adapting the code from [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/4s8k3f/help_with_finding_whether_a_vertex_is_visible/d57t5a9?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)<sup>1</sup> we can select all the objects which don't contain points in the frustum. However for a production ready check, we would also have to take edges/faces modifiers and reflections into account.+

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view


def check_if_vertices_in_frustum(scene, cam, obj):
    mat_world = obj.matrix_world
    cs, ce = cam.data.clip_start, cam.data.clip_end

    for v in obj.data.vertices:
        co_ndc = world_to_camera_view(scene, cam, mat_world * v.co)
        #check wether point is inside frustum
        if (0.0 < co_ndc.x < 1.0 and
            0.0 < co_ndc.y < 1.0 and
             cs < co_ndc.z <  ce):
            return True
    return False



scene = bpy.context.scene
cam = scene.camera

for obj in scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        if (check_if_vertices_in_frustum(scene, cam, obj)):
            obj.select = False
            # obj.hide_render = False
        else:
            obj.select = True
            # obj.hide_render = True
```

<sup>1</sup> *Help with finding whether a vertex is visible from a camera or not*