# Chroma Key function

Tags: transparency, chromakey

Is there a chroma key function in Blender? This would not only make an object with the chroma key color invisible (alpha = zero), but also any (part of an) object that happens to be behind the chroma key object.

I need this in a 2D set-up, to make text glide from behind an invisible wall against a zero alpha background. If there is another, simpler technique to obtain the same effect, all the better!

Comment: Chroma key should only be used when using a real camera, where generating an alpha channel is not possible. For CG work generating an alpha channel along with the RGB information is quite easy and more precise. In cycles you can use a holdout material to create transparency. Some options here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48104/can-i-make-an-object-invisible-in-cycles-without-letting-the-camera-see-what-is/48106#48106

Comment: The surface material "holdout" does the job. Perfect!